# Uncaught ReferenceError: GetListItems is not defined

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ajax, sharepoint

I am working on SPFx using react and I am trying to fetch sharepoint list items having more than 5000 items using a REST call.

However when I do this, it goes to the success function and retrieves the first 1000 items as specified. But in the next iteration, this error pops up in the specified line-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GetListItems is not defined

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```js
public componentDidMount() {
  this.GetListItems();
}

public GetListItems() {
  var reactHandler = this;
  var response = response || []; // this variable is used for storing list items 
  var url = '${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_name')/items?$top=1000';     

   jquery.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Data ;", data.d.results);

      response = response.concat(data.d.results);
      console.log("Items are1;", response);

      if (data.d.__next) {
        url = data.d.__next;
        this.GetListItems(); // error in this line
        console.log("concat", this.response);
      } else {
        return response;
      }

      reactHandler.setState({
        items: response,
        filteredItems: response
      }, () => {
        console.log("Items are;", this.state.items);
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      // error handler code goes here
      console.log("error")
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: We can't help with the error you've shown because you havent provided the code from where you call `GetListItems()` - it's probably out of scope. Also note that there are other problems too though. You need to wrap the `url` value in quotes so that it's recognised as a string, and you cannot return any value from the async `$.ajax()` call. You need to work with promises/await instead.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I missed the quotes. I added now. I am calling GetListItems() from componentDidMount() as you can see.

Comment: I removed the return and checked. The output is still the same.The error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong! It was a scope issue since I used ES5 syntax in my success function. I changed it to ES6 ie., used an arrow function. Here is my updated code-

```
public componentDidMount() {
                    var response = response || [];  // this variable is used for storing list items
                    var url = `${this.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items?$top=1000`;
                    this.GetItems(response, url);
            
                }
        
    

public GetItems = (response, url) => {            
           
            jquery.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                },
    
    
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log("Data ;", data.d.results);    
                    response = response.concat(data.d.results);
                    console.log("Items are;", response);
                    if (data.d.__next) {
                        url = data.d.__next;
                        this.GetItems(response, url);
                        console.log("concat", response.length);
                    }
    
                    this.setState({
                        items: response,
                        filteredItems: response
    
                    }, () => {
                        console.log("Items are;", this.state.items);
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // error handler code goes here
                    console.log("error")
                }
            });
    
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I test the code with js directly.

I made some changes to the code for your reference：

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('testn')/items?$top=1000`;
      GetListItems(url)
    })
    
     var response = response || [];
    function GetListItems(url) {
      
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
          console.log("Data ;", data.d.results.length);

          response = response.concat(data.d.results);
          console.log("Items are1;", response);

          if (data.d.__next) {
            url = data.d.__next;
            GetListItems(url); // error in this line
            console.log("concat",response);
          } else {
            return response;
          }

          // reactHandler.setState({
          //   items: response,
          //   filteredItems: response
          // }, () => {
          //   console.log("Items are;", this.state.items);
          // });
        },
        error: function (error) {
          // error handler code goes here
          console.log("error")
        }
      })
    }
  </script>
```

Test result:
[image]
Updated:
[image]
Updated code:

```
this.state={
      Response:[]
    }
    var Response=this.state.Response;
        Response.concat(data.d.results);
        this.setState({Response})
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. So, you are saying that you were able to achieve this? Like retrieve more than 5000 items, 1000 at a time? Because I see concat undefined

Comment: I am using a class component and I cannot define a function like how you mentioned. So in order to call that my way, I need to use this. Without this, I get an error

Comment: Even if I do ignore the error during compilation,in the runtime, I do get one

Comment: Try to define response in state. Check my update.

Comment: I will try and update accordingly. Thanks

Comment: In SPFX,I usually use pnp js.https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225738/discussion-between-priyankarao-and-amos-msft).

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong. It was a scope issue in success function since I was using ES5 syntax. Changed it to ES6 syntax ie., used an arrow function and it recognizes the function now.

Comment: Good job.You could post this solution and mark it as answer.